# How to get library built by libtool?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, config, libtool

I'm currently building the `harfbuzz` library in linux.  I see it uses `libtool` which I am not familiar with.  The build appears to complete successfully but there is not `.a` file or `.so` file that I would normally expect to see.  Instead there are a bunch of `.lo`, `.la`, `.pc`, and other files produced. How do I obtain the library?

Here is the output of the build:

```
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-blob.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-buffer-serialize.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-buffer.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-common.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-face.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-font.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-tag.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-set.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-shape.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-shape-plan.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-shaper.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-unicode.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-warning.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-font.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-layout.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-map.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-shape.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-shape-complex-arabic.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-shape-complex-default.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-shape-complex-hangul.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-shape-complex-hebrew.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-shape-complex-indic.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-shape-complex-indic-table.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-shape-complex-myanmar.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-shape-complex-thai.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-shape-complex-tibetan.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-shape-complex-use.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-shape-complex-use-table.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-shape-normalize.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-ot-shape-fallback.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-fallback-shape.lo
  CXX      libharfbuzz_la-hb-glib.lo
  GEN      libharfbuzz.la
  CXX      main-main.o
  CXXLD    main
  CXX      test-test.o
  CXXLD    test
  CXX      test_buffer_serialize-test-buffer-serialize.o
  CXXLD    test-buffer-serialize
  CXX      test_size_params-test-size-params.o
  CXXLD    test-size-params
  CXX      test_would_substitute-test-would-substitute.o
  CXXLD    test-would-substitute
  GEN      harfbuzz.pc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the libraries.  They were generated in the `src/.libs` directory.